# I keep getting a "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string" error

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not sure why this is happening, I've been using Node.JS for a few months now and this has never happened to me before. The project files are still empty, I just started this new project and tried to run it to see if I got everything set up and working.

I used express instead of http,
mongoose and body-parser, and ejs for the client side.

Here is my whole main js code:

```
//All the requirements we will be using
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const dbURI = "URI";

//Connects to the DB
mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err)=> {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to the database!');
    }
})

//Sets the settings for the website
app.use('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('css'));
app.use(express.static('scripts'))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//Starts the server
app.listen(3000, 'localhost', (req, res)=> {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log('Listening @ port 3000... ');
    }
})

//All the web routes
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home'})
})
```

If  somebody could help me understand why I keep getting this error, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of `app.use('view engine', 'ejs')`:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

The view engine actually is not a middleware, but a configuration parameter for the application.